# How can I start a spark job streaming a delta table change feed from it's yet-to-come changes?

Tags: apache-spark, databricks, spark-streaming

I'm working with this job that reads the change feed from 2 distinct delta tables, does some computing, unions the two tables and merges the results in a 3rd delta table.

I'm working with Databricks btw.

Here is a code sample

```scala
val stream1 = spark
    .readStream
    .option("readChangeFeed", "true")
    .table(table1)
    // [...]

val stream2 = spark
    .readStream
    .option("readChangeFeed", "true")
    .table(table2)
    // [...]

stream1.unionByName(stream2)
    .writeStream
    .option("checkpointLocation", checkpointLocation)
    .foreachBatch((rows: Dataset[Row], _: Long) => {
        DeltaTable
            .forName(spark, table3).as("target")
            .merge(
                rows.toDF.as("new"),
                "target.id = new.id"
            )
            .whenMatched($"new.a_field".isNull)
            .delete()
            .whenMatched()
            .updateAll()
            .whenNotMatched()
            .insertAll()
            .execute()
    })
    .trigger(AvailableNow)
    .start()
    .awaitTermination()
```

The change feed is huge so I don't want to process everything from start or it's going to take too much time. I'd rather just fill `table3` using a one-off notebook (workflow) that is going to read `table1` and `table2` and then have my actual job just start from the next version to come.

So I thought I may be able to use the `.option("startingVersion", "latest")` to do so. As a matter of fact it does not behave as I expect it should.
I was under the impression it that upon the first run it would not process anything then write the checkpoint. However it doesn't do that last part as expected. It creates the folders and the `metadata` file but besides a single uuid in the metadata file's json there is nothing.

[image: empty checkpoint]

Of course if I remove the `latest` flag and start it again it reads everything from the start. With that experience, `latest` just doesn't seem to fit the `AvailableNow` trigger. Maybe it's made for `Continuous` trigger ?

**Sub-question here: how is `latest` expected to work ?**

A few solutions that I have found but that I don't like:

`table1` has a current version of `83`. So of course I tried setting the starting version to `84`. But then the job just fails as the version doesn't exist. I *could* leave it like that until version `84` actually spawns but it feels dirty. It's still a solution though.

Another solution that I haven't tried yet but I guess could work is to set the startingVersion to `83` then filter out any row with that `_commit_version`. At least my job wouldn't fail. However it would be processing useless data. It's more costly than a single failure.

Anyway, the question remains for me:

**How can I bootstrap a job then have it only read new changes in a cost efficient way ?**

Another way I could ask this question but already leans toward a solution:

**How can I bootstrap a checkpoint so that my job only reads changes that come after an initial load in a proper way ?**

Thanks